# No subject alternative DNS name matching www.billiving.com found. Why this caused and how to solve?

Tags: java, ssl, dns, ssl-certificate, java-security

I have integration test suite for www.billiving.com API. when that API call endpoint should be https://www.billiving.com.

my test suite work perfectly on windows. however when it move to ubuntu 14.x it get failed with following exception. [1]

so i have written this [2] code to test it beyond the test suite. still it fail with same exception.

so i tried to import billiving.com certificate to JKS but still it fail with same exception.

i know as a solution we can override the verify method in Verifier class and return as true. but i need proper solution as this can lead security issues.

1) why this error and why its only on linux.

2) how can we solve this with proper solution

API URL:
https://www.billiving.com/

[1] exception:

```
>     javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: java.security.cert.CertificateException: No subject alternative DNS
> name matching www.billiving.com found.    at
> com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:174)
>   at
> com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.fatal(SSLSocketImpl.java:1747)
>   at
> com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Handshaker.java:241)
>   at
> com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Handshaker.java:235)
>   at
> com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.ClientHandshaker.serverCertificate(ClientHandshaker.java:1209)
>   at
> com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.ClientHandshaker.processMessage(ClientHandshaker.java:135)
>   at
> com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.Handshaker.processLoop(Handshaker.java:593)
>   at
> com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.Handshaker.process_record(Handshaker.java:529)
>   at
> com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:943)
>   at
> com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1188)
>   at
> com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1215)
>   at
> com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1199)
>   at
> sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.afterConnect(HttpsClient.java:434)
>   at
> sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:166)
>   at
> sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1195)
>   at
> java.net.HttpURLConnection.getResponseCode(HttpURLConnection.java:379)
>   at
> sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getResponseCode(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:318)
>   at Application.main(Application.java:20)  Caused by:
> java.security.cert.CertificateException: No subject alternative DNS
> name matching www.billiving.com found.    at
> sun.security.util.HostnameChecker.matchDNS(HostnameChecker.java:193)
>   at sun.security.util.HostnameChecker.match(HostnameChecker.java:77)
>   at
> com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkIdentity(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:264)
>   at
> com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkServerTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:250)
>   at
> com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.ClientHandshaker.serverCertificate(ClientHandshaker.java:1188)
```

[2] sample code :

```
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;

public class Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        URL url;
        try {
            url = new URL(args[0]);

        HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        connection.setInstanceFollowRedirects(false);
        connection.setRequestMethod("GET");

        if (connection.getResponseCode() >= 400) {
            System.out.println("ERROR "+ connection.getResponseCode());
        } else {
            System.out.println("Success");
        }

        System.out.println("Connection Crated");



        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }


}
```

command to use above code:

```
java Application https://www.billiving.com
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The real certificate of this site has the correct host name. But you get this certificate only if you are using SNI ([Server Name Indication](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server_Name_Indication)). Older Java versions do not support SNI (should be supported since Java 7), so maybe you need to upgrade your *unspecified* version.

Comment: it was great call. yes its worked. it was in java 6 and when i updated to java 7 it worked for me. thanks for the time :)