# Maven Ant Tasks, deploying to https

Tags: maven, ssl, ant, wagon

I am trying to deploy a deb-file to a nexus with ssl but I am getting the error message "No subject alternative DNS name matching..."

my build target in ant looks like this:

```
<target name="deploy">
    <artifact:pom id="mypom" file="pom.xml"/>

    <artifact:install-provider artifactId="wagon-ssh" version="1.0-beta-2" />

    <artifact:deploy file="target/foo.deb">
        <remoteRepository url="https://bar" />
        <pom refid="mypom" />
    </artifact:deploy>
</target>
```

How do I configure the wagon? I just want to ignore the certificate.

Comment: What version of Java are you running? See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29982700/no-subject-alternative-dns-name-matching-www-billiving-com-found-why-this-cause

Comment: 7. And I cannot change that, bc it is a work pc